# Equipotential surface

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, conductors

If we place a charge near a conducting sphere and the sphere isn't grounded since the opposite charge will get induced on nearer side and same sign (as of outer charge) charge will get induced on farther side will the surface of conductor still be equipotential because if we take two points one nearest to the outer charge and another farthest from outer charge ( diametrically opposite points )but both points on surface of conductor the sign of charges will be diffrent at these points so will they still be at same potential

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your conductor will always have the same potential, if not the charges would move.

Answer (score 0):

You have non uniform charge distribution on the surface of the conducting sphere. The combination (you can add the effects, since it can be considered a linear process) of the electric field produced by the "external" charge, and the electric field produced by the non-uniform charge distribution on the sphere leads to the result that the surface of the sphere is an equipotential surface.

Otherwise, as you can read in the answer by trula, if you have a non-equipotential surface you end up with a electric field that is not perpendicular to the surface of the sphere and this would make electric charges move (you can often assume a linear relationship $\mathbf{e}= \rho \mathbf{j}$ between the electric field $\mathbf{e}$ and the current density $\mathbf{j}$, being $\rho$ the resistivity of the material).

Answer (score 0):

For the charges on a surface to be equipotential, the charges need to be in equilibrium so that they do not move. If you remove the charge that induced the movement of the surface charge on the sphere, the forces between the surface charge on the sphere will cause the charge to redistribute itself uniformly over the surface of the sphere so as to be in equilibrium and the surface equipotential. That tells you charge on the sphere with the external charge present was not equipotential.

Hope this helps.